# "This list" search does not search list items

Tags: 2007, search, list

When I select "This List" in the Search function and search a document library, I get the expected results, but if I do the same with a list (for example, a contacts list), I get "No results matching your search were found."

The Advanced Settings for the list allows items to be searched and searching using "This Site" returns the list items correctly.

Any suggestions?

**Edit 2011-01-26:** It seems that if I have a contacts list

> http://servername/Lists/Sales%20Contacts/AllItems.aspx

and search "This List" for "Malone", the search URL is:

> http://servername/searchcenter/Pages/results.aspx?k=Malone&cs=This List&u=http%3a%2f%2fservername%2fSales+Contacts

The "u" parameter "http%3a%2f%2fservername%2fSales+Contacts" translates to "http://servername/Sales+Contacts", missing the "/Lists". If I change the parameter to "http%3a%2f%2fservername%2fLists%2fSales+Contacts" it works! This would explain why document libraries are still searchable; they reside directly below the site.

So the question now is - why is it leaving out "/Lists"?

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure we're not overlooking something, are you searching with whole names when you do the contact search? Partial word searches are not supported.   Also, what does the search results screen say when you do the list search?

Comment: Yes - I am using full words in the search.

When I do a list search, it returns "No results matching your search were found.
Check your spelling. Are the words in your query spelled correctly?
Try using synonyms. Maybe what you're looking for uses slightly different words.
Make your search more general. Try more general terms in place of specific ones.
Try your search in a different scope. Different scopes can have different results."

Searching the site for the same word returns one result: the contact I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry. That's a tough one.  I've tried on a couple different servers and I can't recreate your issue. Check out this post: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointsearch/thread/906045d8-8782-4c39-be1b-7632f7239019/ See the response by Shane Young on Feb 8, 2008. It appears that if your Alternate Access Mapping for the default zone does not match your content source URL, you should make them match then do a full crawl. Different things in this thread worked for different people. That one makes the most sense to me. Can you check your settings?

Comment: Ah - that was helpful. One post on that thread asks:

> Look at the query string parameter u. "u" parameter has a url value. Is that a valid url value. Can you go to that url(after appropriately decoding it).

I have updated my question with my results.

My alternate access mappings seem to be correct - http://servername is the default.

Comment: Since OP found it helpful I have upvoted this answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to search SharePoint lists and document libraries is to using a third party web part like the one at http://demo.metadatasys.com.